# Physical sides of Electromagnetic Wave Propagation as nonlinear in metal

Tags: electricity, metals

This Wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_canonical_transformation#Electromagnetic_wave_propagation) says that the electromagnetic wave propagation in air can be done by Freshnel transform:

$$U_{0}(x,y) = - \frac{j}{\lambda} \frac{e^{jkz}}{z} 
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
e^{j \cdot \frac{k}{2z}[ (x - x_{i})^2 + (y - y_{i})^2 ] }
\cdot U_{i} (x_{i}, y_{i}) dx_{i} \, dy_{i}$$

with $k = 2\pi / \lambda$ is wave number, $\lambda$ wavelength, $z$ distance of propagation, and $j$ imaginary unit.

However, this does not confirm me because you can explain this by matrices i.e. LTC (shearing). 
I think this Freshnel tranform is some kind of TFD (time-frequency distribution) and linear one. 
I would like to have some nonlinear operator to present Electromagnetic wave propagation in any material.

**Is there any good presentation of the electromagnetic wave propagation in any material as nonlinear?**
What are the physical sides of selecting such a presentation?
What are the restrictions of presenting the propagation as nonlinear transform?

Comment: Why do you think EM waves *should* behave non-linearly in metals?

Comment: @ACuriousMind In low energetic waves, I think they do. If you have high energetic situations, there is only one path so reaching linear behavior.